# Cannot compile while curl_easy_init() within a member function?

Tags: c++, curl, linker, libcurl

I wrote this below and it works only when i `curl_easy_init()` outside `createEasyHandle`, in the main  function.

in using visual studio 2013

if i try to `curl_easy_init()` in `creatEasyHandle` i cant compile and i get unresolved external errors.

In short, everything works!! when i pass the handle in to `createEasyHandle`, but when I try to `curl_easy_init()` within `createEasyHandle` it tells me i have unresolved external link error 2001.

```
BOOL Connect::createEasyHandle(CURL* easyHandle){
BOOL retVal = FALSE;
CURLcode result = curl_easy_setopt(easyHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com/");
if (result == CURLE_OK){

    result = curl_easy_perform(easyHandle);

    if (result == CURLE_OK){

        char* plocalIP;
        CURLcode easyRet = curl_easy_getinfo(easyHandle,  CURLINFO_LOCAL_IP, &plocalIP);
        privateIP = plocalIP;

        retVal = TRUE;
    }
}

curl_easy_cleanup(easyHandle);
return retVal;
}
```

the error

```
__imp_curl_easy_(all the functions i tried to use)LINKERROR 2001
```

the code which gives compile error/ LINK error 2001

```
BOOL Connect::createEasyHandle(){
    BOOL retVal = FALSE;
    CURL* easyHandle = curl_easy_init();
```

instead of

```
BOOL Connect::createEasyHandle(CURL* easyHandle){
    BOOL retVal = FALSE;
```

Comment: Is it a code that have problems? at which line? Linker error - is a compilation error, not runtime.

Comment: I get compile errors. this code runs fine but when curl_easy_init() is inside createEasyHandle. it does not compile.

Comment: And how should we understand what going wrong at your code with problems if instead of problem code you show us code that is normally working?

Comment: just add curl_easy_init() to createEasyHandle, pretty straight forward..

Comment: Are you building your project in an IDE? If so which one/version?